# Try to Display Number of Choice Selected at Any Time on Django Form MultipleChoiceField

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am building an application for a real estate project. As part of this, I have "listing" items in my database that I filter and display on my SearchTool.html page. One of the search functions includes a button that says "Select Property Type" on it. When you click the button, a small popup displays all of the multiple-choice field options from my Django form. I want the button to show how many choices are selected so that if the popup is closed you don't have to reopen it to know how many are active. Currently, it seems to mostly work. The popup works great. But, the counter has some problems. When I select exactly on the checkbox then the counter works fine but when I select the text to toggle the choice the counter doesn't catch it. When I click on the text like this, the backend still registers it because it sorts my listings correctly. So, there is an issue with the html/js not registering when I select the text vs the box itself.

I am new to Django so please let me know if this question has been answered or if I am missing something obvious.

Here is some of my relevant code, let me know if I need to include anything else:

SearchTool.html:

```
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">
                        <label for="id_Property_type" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label text-end text-uppercase fw-bold" style="font-size: 1.75rem;">Property Type:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <!-- Add a button to trigger the popup -->
                            <button type="button" onclick="showPropertyTypes()" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Select Property Type
                                <span id="propertyTypeCounter" class="badge bg-secondary">All</span>
                            </button>
                    
                            <!-- Hidden div to display property types when the button is clicked -->
                            <div id="propertyTypePopup" class="popup" style="display: none;">
                                {% for choice in form.Property_type %}
                                    <div id="propertyTypePopupA">
                                        <button type="button" onclick="selectPropertyType(this, event);">{{ choice }}</button>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS (located below the above html right after the ):

```
 <script>
        var popup = document.getElementById("propertyTypePopup");
        var counter = document.getElementById("propertyTypeCounter");
    
        function showPropertyTypes() {
            if (popup.style.display === "block") {
                popup.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                popup.style.display = "block";
                popup.style.top = "50px"; // Adjust as needed
                popup.style.left = "0";   // Adjust as needed
            }
        }
    
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.btn') && !event.target.matches('.popup') && !event.target.closest('.popup')) {
                popup.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
    
        popup.onmouseleave = function () {
            popup.style.display = "none";
        };
    
        function selectPropertyType(button) {
            // Ensure that the 'button' variable refers to the correct button element
            var selectedButton = button.tagName === 'BUTTON' ? button : button.closest('button');
            selectedButton.classList.toggle('selected');
            updateCounter();
        }
    
        function updateCounter() {
            var selectedCount = document.querySelectorAll('#propertyTypePopupA button.selected').length;
            counter.innerText = selectedCount;
        }
    </script>
```

Relevant part of Forms.py:

```
 Property_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Property_type, required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```